# Select query in mariadb not giving result when using extended characters

Tags: php, mariadb

I have a mariadb databses encoded with utf8mb4. My website is encoded with utf8.
When I run a query with an extended character in it, mariadb is not returning any row.
I have in php:

```
$cn->query("SELECT * FROM informatie WHERE informatie LIKE '%máchtig%'");
```

There is a record in this table (informatie) that has the word máchtig in the column informatie.
I suppose it has something to do with the encoding.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may look into MATCH instead. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match

Comment: There are various places that character encoding is set.  I suggest you have your PHP code run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'` and examine the output to check that they are all set correctly.  Then I would also check the character encoding of your actual PHP file too

Comment: Set your connection character set to utf8mb4 or cast the like expression: `SELECT * FROM informatie WHERE informatie LIKE _utf8mb4 '%máchtig%'`

Comment: Thanks all of you.
The second idea was the one what helped me. It showed that things were stored in the database with htmlentities. But ofcourse was this not visible,because the browser showed the character.